# Making an extra for python markdown2

Tags: python, markdown

Are there any instructions on how to do this, or samples of existing extras? I can't find either. I did find instructions for how to make extensions to python markdown, though, but I don't know if the same syntax applies.

Here is the project on github: https://github.com/trentm/python-markdown2

Here is a promising tutorial for python markdown: http://achinghead.com/python-markdown-adding-insert-delete.html

Comment: Python-Markdown and Python-Markdown2 are two different (competing) libraries. AFAIK, they do not use the same extension API. Why do you want to use Python-Markdown2? If it is for their stated performance benefits, you may what to verify them yourself (or read [this](http://lepture.com/en/2014/markdown-parsers-in-python)). If you're using Python-Markdown, a more recent tutorial is [here](https://github.com/waylan/Python-Markdown/wiki/Tutorial:-Writing-Extensions-for-Python-Markdown). Full discloser: I'm the maintainer of the Python-Markdown library.

Comment: The people I was going to help chose markdown2. I believe that they could be open to change it.